# UIScrollView according to background

Tags: ios, storyboard

I've an UIScrollView and I want to update his size according to his UIImageView background to exactly stay in the paper.

That the constraints I've added.
[image]

In othe size the result is wrong for example iphone 6s plus:
(It's fine in iPhone4s obviously)
[image]

Comment: you shouldnt give equal width/height constraint, instead try giving the aspect ratio constraint

Comment: it isn't possible with align x and align y to subview

Comment: ctrl drag the scrollview to its superview and select center x,y,aspect ratio constraints and click on add constraints button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the picture with the rubber, marker, pencil and the stack of paper is a single UIImageView, and that the UIScrollView is on top of those.

If that is the case, you will have a very hard time to do what you are trying to, as you will have dynamically no idea how the stack of paper will be resized.

My solution would be to isolate each part of your drawing (the rubber, the marker, the pencil and the paper stack) in separate UIImageViews, then add the scrollView as a subview of the `paper stack` view: [see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0ZAj.png).

From there, add constraints to resize the scrollview dynamically according to its superview.

Comment: That is the way I thought. Unfortunately there isn't no a fast way. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you used full image, you have to use multiplier, not constant.
To do it, you need to calculate the position rate and use it for multiplier.
I've attached some images for example. It will be helpful for your project.
Only need to get the position rate and size rate of the object in origin image.

Setting multiplier for equal width with super view
[image: Setting multiplier for equal width with super view]
Setting multiplier for Align center X with super view
[image: Setting multiplier for Align center X with super view]
Result in iPhone 4s
[image]
Result in iPhone 6
[image]